# Подписывание скриптов

Tags: powershell

Не могу подписать скрипт, все время выскакивает ошибка `UnknownError`. Смена кодировки файла скрипта не помогает.

Подписываю скрипт следующей командой:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature "d:\dist1.ps1" @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\Krox -codesigning)[0]
```

Ошибка возвращается в следующем виде:

```
SignerCertificate          Status         Path
-----------------          ------         ----
                           UnknownError   dist1.ps1
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавте в вопрос команды с помощью которых вы подписываете скрипт и полный текст ошибки

Answer (score 1):

На Connect есть [баг, описывающий похожую проблему](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/483431/set-authenticodesignature-fails-on-scripts-created-from-ise): похоже, что `Get-ChildItem` не отдает приватный ключ.

> My suspicion is that because `Get-ChildItem` doesn't prompt for the
>   certificate's password it's only getting the Public Key portion and
>   not the Private Key portion actually needed to sign the script. Hope
>   this helps!

Попробуйте так экспортировать сертификат с приватным ключом и сделать так:

```
$Сert = Get-PfxCertificate .\myCertificate.pfx
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -Filepath 'd:\dist1.ps1' -Cert $Cert -IncludeChain All
```

Comment: К большому сожалению Ваш совет не помог. При попытке подписать скрипт вылетает все та же ошибка...